# Image slider using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to make an image slider but i don't get how it works.

when I press a button like 'next', I can make an image be shown using show(), but not a slide.

Please let me know how the image slider(left-to-right animation) works.

I apologize I didn't attach the code. I just wanna know the way to make.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please show your code and we can better help you :)

Comment: Use animate() function http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Comment: @KyleSevenoaks sorry, I removed my code because It didn't work that well. To begin with re-making the image slider, I asked the question here first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the offset capability

You basically create a container that is smaller than the underlying content then animate the slide using offset

Comment: oh, I used only the animate(). I will try. Thank you very much.